Instruct symfony to read _wdt tool bar from https
I depoyed a site to "https://develop.domain.com". The environment is 'dev' and the page "https://develop.domain.com/_profiler/" works well.
When I access the site itself ("https://develop.domain.com") the profiler bar is not visible and, in network log, I see that it tries to access "http://develop.domain.com/_wdt/..." (note this is http not https).
Is there a way to configure what base URL should the profiler toolbar use?
Note: our firewall prevents http, it only allows https.

Are you accessing the webserver directly, or is it sitting behind a reverse proxy, load balancer, or similar?

There is a reverse proxy in between

Have you set your configuration as shown here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html ?

Yes, it does not work.

I whitelisted all trusted_proxies, but it still does not work.
Although I have a redirect http->https in place, _wdt still doesn't work. I think CORS is not so forgiving.
I do not understand why symfony even tries to access http at all.

More information: I see this error: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://develop.domain.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://develop.domain.com/_wdt/xxxxxxxx?XDEBUG_IGNORE=1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

the reason this occurs is because of the server being behind a reverse proxy, and the proxy configuration in symfony.
